# Call Revert Exception when trying to call contract made by a smart contract factory in Hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, factory

This function deploys a new erc721 smart contract. It works because when i try to call the instance of the contract from within the function it works. But when I am writing my hardhat tests this is the error I get:

From Log:

```
     Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="name()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.6.4)
```

From Local Node:  `WARNING: Calling an account which is not a contract`

My Function:

```
    function createCollection(string memory name_, string memory symbol_, string memory baseURI_, uint256 maxSupply,address owner) external returns (address collection) {
        bytes memory bytecode = type(ERC721W).creationCode;
        bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(name_, symbol_, block.number ));
        assembly {
            collection := create2(0, add(bytecode, 32), mload(bytecode), salt)
        }
        ERC721W(collection).initialize(name_, symbol_, baseURI_, maxSupply, owner);
        console.log('Inside contract', ERC721W(collection).symbol()); // for testing (works)
        allCollections.push(address(collection));
        emit CollectionCreated(name_, symbol_, baseURI_, allCollections.length, address(collection));
        return collection;
    }
```

My Test:

```
    it("Should deploy a contract", async function () {
      const { ercFactory, owner, account1 } = await loadFixture(deployFixture);

      let name = "test";
      let symbol = "tst";
      let baseURI = "https://test";
      let maxSupply = 10;
      let ownerAddress = account1.address;
      let newAddress = await ercFactory.callStatic.createCollection(
        name,
        symbol,
        baseURI,
        maxSupply,
        ownerAddress
      );

      console.log("new address", newAddress);

      let ERC721 = await ethers.getContractAt("ERC721W", newAddress);
      //console.log(ERC721);
      console.log(await ERC721.name());
      console.log(await ethers.provider.getCode(newAddress));
      //expect(await ERC721.owner()).to.be.equal(account1.address);
    });
```

Calling any function will throw this error and I have tried them all. I dont have any other contract with the same name so getContractAt should be working. not sure here

Comment: As much as I have seen, whenever we try to get a return value from functions which are not `view` or `pure`, we do not get any return values. Rather, we get the information of the whole block. The return values are only accessed when these functions call each other internally. Maybe that's why it is not considering `newAddress` as a contract address.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but it looks to me like you aren't actually deploying an ERC721, just `staticcall`ing in to get the address

Answer (score 0):

Hey can you share output of commandline....

And can you try calling functions in `newAddress` which you have  generated like in contract or is there any output showing of consloe of contract